# IntelliJ Tab button

Tags: intellij-idea, tabs

Good afternoon!
I've got something like this  (| is position of cursor):

```
System.out.println("|")`;
```

After clicking TAB Button I'd like it to exit the quotes instead of making couple spaces.
Is there any way to change it in IntelliJ 2016.3?

Comment: No. What you can do is press Ctrl-Shift-Enter (Edit | Complete Current Statement) to add a new line after the current one and move the caret there.

Comment: I don't know if you have ever used Visual Studio, but there is that option. You write something in quotes, click tab and cursor moves to position after quote. I find it very useful. What for I need a tabulation between quotes if I could write "\t" ?